# Fiware KeyRock sending Ajax requests with access token

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fiware

I'm building a client for a FIWARE KeyRock GE instance in Javascript.

I have a function for querying the instance (after a successful login flow in which I received an access_token):

```
keyrockManager.query = function (uri, method, params, callback) {
    if (params == null)
        params = {};
    params.access_token = keyrockManager.getAccessToken();
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: KeyrockConfig.defaultInstanceUrl + uri,
            type: method,
            data: params,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    );
};
```

I actually thought that an open API will allow all origins but it apparently not, so I'm using `jsonp` because of the CORS issue.

For some reason I'm keep getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
index.js:26 Error: jQuery1113013546996610239148_1445936551798 was not called(…)
```

Any idea how to solve it ?